# how to edit node using Analyser in dart

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

How to edit a source file in dart using analyser.
This is what i tried

```
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/error.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/parser.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/scanner.dart';

String src = """
Dynamism d = new Dynamism(expert:true);
main(){
var o = new Object();
d.on(o).hi = 'bye';
}
""";
main() {
var ast = parseCompilationUnit(src, parseFunctionBodies: true);
print('initial value: ');
print(ast.toSource());
var v = new Visitor();
ast.visitChildren(v);
print('After modification:');
print(ast.toSource());
}
class Visitor extends RecursiveAstVisitor {
@override
 visitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpression node) {
//filter
var p = new RegExp(r'.*\.on\(\w\)');
if (!p.hasMatch(node.toString())) return;

//replace
SimpleStringLiteral ssl = _create_SimpleStringLiteral(node);
node.parent.accept(new NodeReplacer(node, ssl));
}
}

SimpleStringLiteral _create_SimpleStringLiteral(AstNode node) {
String new_string = modify(node.toString());
int line_num = node.offset;
//holds the position and type
StringToken st = new StringToken(TokenType.STRING, new_string, 
line_num);
return new SimpleStringLiteral(st, new_string);
}

String modify(String s) {
List parts = s.split('=');
var value = parts[1];
List l = parts[0].split('.');
String dynamism = l.sublist(0, l.length - 1).join('.');
String propertyName = l.last.trim();
return '${dynamism}.set("${propertyName}",${value})';
}
```

but it's throwing error on SimpleStringLiteral, saying it is an Abstract Class. Please help me to edit 'bye' to 'goodbye'.i think previous version of dart has its implementation but now its abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
return new SimpleStringLiteral(st, new_string) try
**return astFactory.simpleStringLiteral(st, new_string);**

```
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/standard_ast_factory.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/error.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/parser.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/scanner.dart';

String src = """
Dynamism d = new Dynamism(expert:true);
main(){
var o = new Object();
d.on(o).hi = 'bye';
}
""";
main() {
var ast = parseCompilationUnit(src, parseFunctionBodies: true);
print('initial value: ');
print(ast.toSource());
var v = new Visitor();
ast.visitChildren(v);
print('After modification:');
print(ast.toSource());
}
class Visitor extends RecursiveAstVisitor {
@override
 visitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpression node) {
//filter
var p = new RegExp(r'.*\.on\(\w\)');
if (!p.hasMatch(node.toString())) return;

//replace
SimpleStringLiteral ssl = _create_SimpleStringLiteral(node);
node.parent.accept(new NodeReplacer(node, ssl));
}
}

SimpleStringLiteral _create_SimpleStringLiteral(AstNode node) {
String new_string = modify(node.toString());
int line_num = node.offset;
//holds the position and type
StringToken st = new StringToken(TokenType.STRING, new_string, 
line_num);
return astFactory.simpleStringLiteral(st, new_string);
}

String modify(String s) {
List parts = s.split('=');
var value = parts[1];
List l = parts[0].split('.');
String dynamism = l.sublist(0, l.length - 1).join('.');
String propertyName = l.last.trim();
return '${dynamism}.set("${propertyName}",${value})';
}
```